# How can I get red mana immediately?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am making a mana ramp deck, and I was wondering what other ways can I get 1 red other than tapping lands. I don't mind paying life or discarding that creature, like Simian Spirit Guide, but I want to be able to play it out of my hand.

Comment: [Manamorphose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=manamorphose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a only a little number of ways you can generate mana right out of your hand. Let's have a list:

- [Simian Spirit Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSimian%20Spirit%20Guide%5d) and [Elvish Spirit Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Spirit%20Guide%5d) can be exiled from your hand for mana
- [Chancellor of the Tangle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChancellor%20of%20the%20Tangle%5d) will provide a single (green) mana for free, and only in the first turn.

Other than those, I'm not aware of any cards that produce mana straight out of your hand. Of course, if you don't mind casting those cards, there are a few more options:

- Spells like [Desperate Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesperate%20Ritual%5d) from your hand, though these will generally cost you mana
- You can cast creatures like [Priest of Urabrask](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPriest%20of%20Urabrask%5d), which generate mana when they enter the battlefield. Note that at least for the color red, there are no creatures that produce more mana than they cost, but cards like Priest of Urabrask let you filter other colors.
- Similar to the above, you can sacrifice some creatures for mana, even allowing you to "store" some mana for the next turn - [Wild Cantor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWild%20Cantor%5d) would be an example.
- [Treasonous Ogre](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTreasonous%20Ogre%5d) will, once on the battlefield, generate you as much mana as your life total can afford
- [Lotus Petal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLotus%20Petal%5d) can be cast for no mana and sacrificed for a single mana of any color, with other Lotus cards working similarly.
- [Mox Ruby](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMox%20Ruby%5d) can be cast for no mana and tapped immediately. Other Mox cards work similarly.